# cannot convert string to float python value error

Tags: python

I'm in an intro to python class so I don't know much. I'm working on a recipe calculator assignment and I keep on running into an error that states: Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "/Users/Haley/Desktop/Python/assignment 2.py", line 6, in <module>
    ing1amount = input(float("Please enter amount of ingredient 1"))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Please enter amount of ingredient 1'
```

I don't know what this means or how to really fix it, so anything helps. Thanks!

```
#Let the user input the name of the recipe
recipe = (input("Enter the name of your recipe: "))

#Let the user input ingredients and their amounts
ingredient1 = input("Please enter ingredient 1: ")
ing1amount = input(float("Please enter amount of ingredient 1"))
ingredient2 = input("Please enter ingredient 2: ")
ing2amount = input(float("Please enter amount of ingredient 2"))
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#Let the user input ingredients and their amounts
ingredient1 = input("Please enter ingredient 1: ")
ing1amount = input(float("Please enter amount of ingredient 1"))
```

Your first line gets the input as a string.  The second line *should* convert that string to a float.  however, instead of using your result from that first line, you chose to ask for the input again ... but the you decided to convert the *prompt* string to a float, which isn't going to work.  The computer has to interpret

float("Please enter amount of ingredient 1")

Before it can continue.  That sentence is *not* a legal `float`, so the program yells.  What you need is to use what you got on the first line, like so:

```
ingredient1 = input("Please enter ingredient 1: ")
ing1amount = float(ingredient1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You tried to convert `"Please enter amount of ingredient 1"` to float

```
ing1amount = float(input("Please enter amount of ingredient 1"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to change the order of float and input.

`ing1amount = float(input("Please enter amount of ingredient 1"))`

The function input() will prompt the user at the command prompt and then return what the user types and then wrapping that with float() will cast the result to a float so that ing1amount will be floating point.